# How to define batches of variates in R

Tags: r

I have lots of files to read as variates in R. Certainly, we can read them one by one, such as：

```
average<-read.csv("average.csv")
variance<-read.csv("variance.csv")
kurt<-read.csv("kurt.csv")
...
```

But it is trivial to do this. Are there some effective ways to realize this aim? I think we can do it in a loop way like the followings：

```
file_names<-c("average.csv","variance.csv","kurt.csv",...)
for(i in 1:n) # n is the number of files to read 
{
  *<-read.csv(file_names[i])
}
```

The problem is how to write codes in "*" part such that we can transform the content in these files to these variates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most idiomatically R approach would be to use work with a list

```
file_names <- c("average.csv","variance.csv","kurt.csv")

# you can get nice names by using tools::file_path_sans_ext
library(tools)
names(file_names) <- file_path_sans_ext(file_names)

dataList <- lapply(file_names, read.csv)


# if you really wanted to copy these to the global environment as objects

list2env(dataList, env = globalenv())
```

Comment: great! your advice is really helpful, Thanks very much!